# How to create custom input types for function defenition for external libraries in Python?

Tags: python, function, types, pep8

I wanted to write functions with detailed types so that during usage of any typecheker e.g. Pylance in VScode you could clearly see the input type. I managed to achieve some result with default input types like `int` and then extended it to `numpy.ndarray`. But this is where I ran into an issue. The code for example function is below:

```
import numpy as np

def get_distance(arr1: np.ndarray, arr2: np.ndarray) -> int:
    """Returns Euclidian distance between 2 points in 3D space

    Args:
        arr1 (np.ndarray[float]): array 1 format [[x,y,z],...]
        arr2 (np.ndarray[float]): array 2 format [[x,y,z],...]

    Returns:
        [int]: Distance between 2 points
    """
    ...

return some_distance
```

When I defined it and then looked for definition under Pylance I managed to get np.ndarray[Unknown, Unknown]:

```
(function) get_distance: (arr1: ndarray[Unknown, Unknown], arr2: ndarray[Unknown, Unknown]) -> int 

Returns Euclidian distance between 2 points in 3D space

Args:
    arr1 (np.ndarray[float]): point array 1
    arr2 (np.ndarray[float]): point array 2

Returns:
    [int]: Distance between 2 points
```

My question is: Is there any way to define an input type such that even when using numpy or any other external library the correct input type would be displayed? For example `np.ndarray[float]` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want?

```py
from numpy.typing import NDArray
import numpy as np

def get_distance(
  arr1: NDArray[np.float64], 
  arr2: NDArray[np.float64]
) -> int:

    # ...

    return some_distance
```

note that you need to use the `typing` submodule from numpy.

for me this method is working.

but note again that this method is not working: `arr: np.ndarray[float]`

as you can see in my editor with LSP-pyright
[image]

this is underlined with `red (error)`

but this method is very fine:
[image]

note again again: you can use any float you like

```py
def get_distance(arr1: NDArray[np.float32] ...
def get_distance(arr1: NDArray[np.float64] ...
def get_distance(arr1: NDArray[np.float128] ...
# also integer
def get_distance(arr1: NDArray[np.int32],
```

but, most important, the data type you use should be defined in the `numpy` module and you have to use `typing` from numpy, not from standard python. why? because numpy has its own datatypes similar to C, because numpy is written in C and compiled and imported in python.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is specific to ndarray -> its typing has 2 arguments - shape and data type.
`TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable` is because you are passing a float as a shape argument, which is supposed to be list-like. (Although personally I got more clear error on Python 3.10 - `TypeError: Too few arguments for numpy.ndarray`

This will work:

```
from typing import Any

def get_distance(arr1: np.ndarray[Any, float], arr2: np.ndarray[Any, float]) -> int:
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood your question, but if you want `np.ndarray[float]`to be shown, that's exactly what you need to pass instead of just `np.ndarray`, like this:

`def get_distance(arr1: np.ndarray[float], arr2: np.ndarray[float]) -> int:`

Comment: I tried this approach already and got a type error `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`. My goal is to define the input type in such a way that not only for example numpy array can be detected as input but also what kind of content numpy array would hold. Also this is not restricted to numpy. For example I want to know if I can somehow pass as type custom data substructures, not only user defined (classes etc) but also from other libraries like tensor from pytorch.